# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Snap Firefox Can't Print

Tags: firefox, 22.04, printing

Recently updated Ubuntu to 22.04.1 LTS. Snap Firefox was installed, and since then, when trying to print, I can only save to pdf. Trying to use the system dialog has the same problem. I can print in Chromium and from the rest of the computer, however.

I have tried the method [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_install-firefox-from-mozilla-builds-for-advanced-users) as a suggested get around, but could not get it to work. Everything worked in the terminal, but it still launches snap firefox.

Does anyone know how to get the printer working in firefox again?

Comment: change FF snap to deb?